# Using xadd for different integer widths

Tags: c++, assembly, x86, atomic, x86-64

I'm currently porting atomic.hpp out of boost for a project and would like to generalize the atomic add function whereby it's templated on the type to add:

```
template <typename T, typename V>
inline T add(volatile T* mem, V val)
{
    T r;

    asm volatile
    (
        "lock\n\t"
        "xadd %1, %0":
        "+m"( *mem ), "=r"( r ):
        "1"( val ):
        "memory", "cc"
    );

    return r;
}
```

I can't find a clear documentation as to wither it's safe to use signed and unsigned 8, 16, 32 and 64 bit numbers with this. Anyone know?

Comment: Have you considered using overloads instead of a template?

Comment: I could do but I'd still need to know wither it's safe to use xadd for signed and unsigned 8 to 64 bit numbers...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use `lock xadd` under IA32 or IA64 with all types of numbers 8, 16, 32 and 64 bit signed or unsigned.
The memory alignment isn't needed but if it is, then the memory access is faster.

From Intel Manual:

> The integrity of the LOCK prefix is
>   not affected by the alignment of the
>   memory field. Memory locking is
>   observed for arbitrarily misaligned
>   fields. This instruction’s operation
>   is the same in non-64-bit modes and
>   64-bit mode.

**Warning!**:

> If the LOCK prefix is used with XADD instruction and the source
>   operand is a memory operand, an
>   undefined opcode exception (#UD) may
>   be generated.

So the source operand must be register and the destination operand is memory address!

Comment: The first quote is flawed, and thus so is the answer: alignment and opperand size aren't the same thing.

Comment: The secon quote is just warning that we must to be carefull haw to use operands to avoid undefined opcode exception. I have changed to warning.